# table-cell height is not fitting to content

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I am using CSS tables to setup a basic grid for a page. The center cell of each row will contain content whereas the first and third "columns" will just be a background color.

The problem I am having has to do with table-cell height. Here is a jsfiddle showing the issue:  http://jsfiddle.net/UQUA9/

```
    /*** The essential CSS for the layout ***/

    html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0pt;
    }

    .Frame {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
    }
    html>/**/body .Frame {
        height: 100%;
    }

    .Row {
        display: table-row;
        height: 1px;
        overflow: hidden; /* commenting this out has no effect. */
    }

    html>body .Row.Expand {
        height: auto; /* commenting this out has no effect. */
    }

    .Row div {
        display: table-cell;
    }
```

Note that in the HeaderRow, the ContentColumn has a large gap beneath the end of the text between it and the MenuRow. I don't understand why the table-cell is padding it out like that. As far as I can see, I don't have any padding or margin set that would account for this empty space. I went with CSS table specifically because it will autofit cell height to content and now it isn't working!

Here's a screen shot to illustrate. The extra grey is the problem. The cell should end on the line after the text but there is a bunch of empty grey. The pink MenuRow should be displayed right after the text in the HeaderRow.

[image: screen shot]

I know I am missing something simple or obvious. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Which part of the layout in your jsFiddle example isn't working?  I'm not too sure what you mean.

Comment: Yep can you add a screenshot?

Comment: @Chuck Remes - Does this fix it? http://jsfiddle.net/9qWkc/

Comment: I added a screen shot so I am hopeful that it clarifies my question. @JoshC your edit did not fix the issue.

Comment: did you mean a space right to dark border saying 'Slogan on top of a header image.' is the issue???

Comment: Problem you have explained - i am not able to find it in the fiddle its working fine for me. can you please specify browser version? may its a browser specific issue...

Comment: @AamirShahzad Look at the "Menu" section in pink on the screen shot. Above it you will see blank grey space (no text). That cell height should only be tall enough to accommodate the text, yet there is all of that empty space. This is Safari 7.0.1. I also see this issue on Firefox 26.0. If you aren't seeing the empty grey in your fiddle, try making the window taller (I am on a 27" monitor).